# Why does MariaDB (MySQL) treat numeric literals as strings?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqldatatypes

Something odd me and my colleague noticed today. If we do this:

```
select id from table
```

where `id` is `integer`, then the result set contains the IDs as integers. All is nice. However when we do this:

```
select 1
```

Then the result set contains the string `"1"`. The actual scenario that led to this was more complicated and involved `ifnull()`, however this is the simplest thing that reproduces the issue.

We're using NodeJS (+Typescript) and TypeORM if it matters. I remember noticing something similar in PHP too, but since PHP is so lax with types anyway, I didn't care much. This time however we're passing the data out to external systems as JSON, so now we need to add `parseInt()` in order to convert the stringly typed numbers back to actual numbers.

But - wtf? Why this behavior?

Comment: *Why this behavior?* MySQL have no any mark which allows to determine does the resultset column datatype must be numeric. So it uses the most common datatype which is string one. If you need numeric datatype strictly make the column context deterministic, for example by `SELECT 1 + 0`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think that HeidiSQL uses the same ODBC driver as JScript...

Comment: @Akina - I would think that the numeric literal `1` kinda implies a numeric type... I can understand that it might be confused which particular type to pick but not a string...

Comment: @Akina I had actually misread the question. It's basically what you say, MySQL sets data types as it sees fit. When dealing with calculated columns I've sometimes had to use `CAST()` even when source values were mere decimal manipulations.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - That's the weird thing - even `cast(1 as integer)` turns out a string...

Comment: I think that you check the datatype wrongly. There is a lot of "translators" between real MySQL output and the place where you check the datatype of a value which may be a lot of times converted already. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3f1801511f6a50b61a04e0ab662622b) - the output clearly shows that the data type is INTEGER. But now there is no any errorneous "helpers".

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE id = 123      -- fine
WHERE id = "123"    -- also fine; the string is converted to a number
WHERE text = "123"  -- also fine (assuming `text` is VARCHAR or TEXT)
WHERE text = 123    -- inefficient because it converts each text to numeric
```

Many APIs "bind" values into queries.  Many of them blindly quote things, regardless of the target.  Note that the above things say that quoting always works "fine".

So, I think that is the "why" that you asked.

And, as you say, PHP, Perl, and other interpreted languages somewhat dominate the space here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Turns out that MySQL interprets numeric literals as 64-bit integers. When doing a `CAST(xxx as integer)` it also treats it as 64-bit integer (you can't specify `tinyint` there) etc. So by the time it gets to NodeJS, it comes along with a tag of `Int64`. If however you select a DB column directly, then you get a more reasonable `Int32` or whatever.

The second part was hidden in the MySQL client after all. What the default `mysql` NPM package does is it checks a connection setting called `bigNumberStrings` which is `true` by default. And if it's true, it keeps 64 bit integers as strings. The reason is obvious - Javascript's `number` type is a 64-bit floating point value and that's smaller than a 64-bit integer. So keeping it as a string preserves fidelity in all cases.

On the other hand, if `bigNumberStrings=false` then it tries to conver the value to a `number` and only leaves it as a string if it's too big. Which is kinda nice yet not always consistent so - handle with care.

I'll have to think which option I want to take.